# Setting up mvc route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a mvc application. I have a project controller, actions are below

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //TODO: Browse
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(long projectId)
    {
        using (var entity = new dixraContext())
        {
            var project = entity.Projects.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == projectId);

            if (project == null)
                return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Error");
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Index", project.UrlName);
        }
    }


    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string projectName)
    {
        using (var entity = new dixraContext())
        {
            var project = entity.Projects.Where(m => m.Name == projectName);
            return View(project);
        }
    }
```

I want to show URL's like

> example.com/Project/ProjectName

But when i enter url as

> example.com/Project/1

Got Error.

> An error occurred while processing your request

. as response. When i enter example.com/Project/Index/1 i go into first action.

I also want to resolve project from id and redirect to usual Project/ProjectName url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got conflicting routes. One way to solve this while leaving your three possible inputs would be checking your input parameter.

Also, your `RedirectToAction` has a string as its second parameter - that overload of `RedirectToAction` treats the second parameter as the controller name, not the route object:

Assuming your routes file looks ok:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Project",
    url: "Project/{projectName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Project", action = "Index" }
);
```

Your controller action might be:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string projectName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(projectName))
    {
        // return your empty view
    }

    int projectId;
    if (int.TryParse(projectName, out projectId))
    {
        projectName = GetProjectNameFromDatabase(projectId);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { projectName });
    }

    // return your view with your model
}
```

There may be a better way, but this will work.